# Why does the elbow turn the wrong way?

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

I'm doing a character for a (very) low poly game. Since I already had a very basic IK rig laying around, I figured I'd adapt its armature to the recently created character.

[image: Original rig]
[image]

However, even after setting the modifiers exactly as they are in the original armature, the elbow bends the wrong way (I'll try to fix that horrendous deformation later).

[image]
[image]

Why does it happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure it bends in a bad way, maybe you need to play with bone 009 to correct the orientation of your elbow sometimes? also I'm not sure about your rigging, why an IK on the upper arm and not only on the lower arm? It seems a little bit unorthodox but maybe you have good reasons to do it this way...

Answer (score 1):

With an IK Constraint, you specify a pole target to control the way the bones bend. I expect you created Bone.009 and Bone.010 to be these pole targets.

Set the pole target to the armature and then the choose the bone to use. To control the direction of the rotation, you adjust the PoleAngle. You can then animate the pole target bone to control the bend during animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you need to a second bone at the elbow that can arrange the correct axis for the elbow to bend on, have a look at beginner rig videos on youtube and they should briefly cover how to set up another bone for these situations.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, clearing the parenting between the mesh and the armature and parenting again solved the problem. When I cleared the parenting, the mesh was rotated 90º, so I rotated it back and redid the parenting. Now it works just as in the original mesh.